# libGDX: Fade in and out between two Screens without Scene2D

Tags: layout, libgdx, fadein, transition

it's me again :)

I'm currently trying to get my libGDX game to completion. However, I have been stuck with the transitions of two screens, so I want that e.g. fade out the menu screen when I start the game and fade in the game screen. I do not use Scene2D and do not know me well with the stages and actors. I would be very glad if someone could help me and solve the problem.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What are you drawing your game on? A Pixmap? Are you just using textures?

Comment: Isn't this as simple as fading the screen to black, moving to the code that draws the other screen, and then fading the screen in?

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry, you can achieve what you aim for without using `Scene2D`. Anyway, there's slightly more work to build the building block system but it's worth it at the end.

## Concept

The concept is to have *game screen manager* that will manage *game screen(s)* you will be operating in the game. That's being said. When you transition from one screen to another, you need such *game screen manager* to control which game screen will be able to `draw`, and which will be able to `update`.

> Normally you will have such manager to manage your game screen anyway. But we can further make use of it to achieve screen transition effect.

Such ability to control will play major role when transition effect kicks in.
For fading in/out effect, let's say you define `T` as total time to complete when one screen transitions to another, `A` is starting screen, `B` is target screen, and `M` is *game screen manager*, the logic behind will be as following

- Fade out `A` until the total time of `T/2` has passed, then you start to do fade in `B`. At beginning when this operation starts, `M` only allows `A` to `update()` its own game logic, but allow both `A` and `B` to `draw()` onto the back buffer screen. Thus `A` can update its own logic code, but both screen can draw.
- When another time duration of `T/2` has passed (now in total of `T`) then you allow `B` be able to `update()`. This means game logic begins to take place inside `B`, and `A` will be disposed as we don't really need anymore.

## How to Draw Content for Both `A` and `B` Together During Transitioning

You might question how can we draw the whole content in alpha manner. Should we mess around with customized shader programming? No need. We still make use of `SpriteBatch`.

The way to do this is to normally draw content of such game screen first, then we draw a black texture of size 2x2 pixel (no need to make it as big as screen resolution) with alpha on top.

Such alpha value will be dynamically calculated by the mechanism we employ in transition effect. Use this technique, draw content from `A` and `B` first before drawing black texture on top of both screen with alpha value to achieve fade in/out transition effect.

## More on Technical Detail

Follow the guideline of the following steps to achieve what I've described above. I'm not going to dwell down to detail. But these steps will likely get you an idea in which implementation is not difficult.

- Implement *game screen manager* to control game state, switching between game screen without any transitioning effect first
- Implement `TransitionState` class. This class accepts minimally two parameters which are starting game screen, and target game screen (others are duration of fading, transitioning effect type, etc) to carry out logic as I explain above in *Concept* and *How to Draw ...* section. In short, this class will be just another game screen (or say game state) for your game, but it will manage two game screens at once when you need to transition from one to another. You can further expand this idea to include more type of transition effect. So `TransitionState` class will be building block of screen transition for you later on. You can take a look and follow along with OMO tutorial by ForeignGuyMike on Youtube. You can start it off from start to have the similar code-base as him, or take a look at this exact [episode starting at 31:08](https://youtu.be/sHERgJyyHxc?t=31m8s) in which he starts coding on this class. He also has a project file for code complete at the episode, so you can take a peek on how he implement.
- Whenever you need to transition from current screen to another, you create a new instance of `TransitionState` then feed them with starting and target game screen. This is the way to tell the game to switch the screen. As behind the scene, it takes time to fade out, then in, dispose old game screen (which faded out), then completely switch to target game screen. Continue normally.

That's all. Please don't be scared with lengthy of text I input to you here as if you get the core concept, you can continue implementing by your own but you need to understand the basic building block of libgdx to get to use it.

Good luck on your implementation.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your loong answer xD. It worked, thank you really much!!

Comment: @Eron Could you please also accept my answer too if it’s the solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help?

https://www.reddit.com/r/libgdx/comments/4zdo03/what_is_the_proper_way_to_fade_inout_of_screens/

And why not use scene2D?

Scene2D demo:
http://www.netthreads.co.uk/2012/02/09/libgdx-scene2d-demo-with-scene-transitions/